# Default Kerberos realm

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, samba, setup, kerberos

I was following the instructions to install Samba from their website, and it said I needed to install the package krb5-user. So I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install krb5-user
```

It started installing, and then this popped up:

[image]

What am I supposed to enter in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enter anything you like.  As, unless you've previously set up a Kerberos KDC, you won't be using Kerberos/GSSAPI auth with Samba, it won't affect your system.

If you have your own domain, I suggest putting its upper-case version there.  Otherwise, you can safely leave it blank.